# time limit exceeded in a nested for-while loop

Tags: java, for-loop, runtimeexception

Could someone help me understand where this time limited exceeding comes from? The context is that in this threeSum method, given an array, I'm trying to record all possible combinations of three numbers that add up to 0. The original question comes from : https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/

```
public class Solution {
public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {

    List<List<Integer>> retList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    Arrays.sort(nums); // O(nlogn)

    for (int i=0; i<nums.length-1; i++){
        int pleft;
        int pright;
        if (i!=0){
            pleft = i-1;
            while((nums[pleft]==nums[i]) && (pleft-1 >=0)){
                pleft--;
            }
        } else {
            pleft = i; 
        }
        if (i!=nums.length-2){
            pright = i+1;
            while((nums[pright]==nums[i]) && (pright+1 < nums.length-1)){
                pright++;
            }
        } else {
            pright = i;
        }
        int sum;
        while (true){
            sum = nums[pleft]+nums[pright]+nums[i];
            if (sum==0){
                List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                temp.add(nums[pleft]);
                temp.add(nums[pright]);
                temp.add(nums[i]);
                retList.add(temp);
                if (pleft-1>=0) pleft--;
                if (pright+1<nums.length-1) pright++;
            } else if (sum>0){
                if (pleft-1>=0) pleft--;
            } else { // less than zero
                if (pright+1<nums.length-1) pright++;
            }

        }
    }


    return retList;
}
```

}

Comment: `while (true) { }` I don't see any `break` in that loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not breaking out of your `while(true)` loop. That code will just run forever and you won't return a value. You need to add a `break` or change the `while (true)` to `while (condition)`